# Expand the function $ \frac{1}{z(1-z)} $ in the neighbourhood of the point $ z = \infty $

Tags: complex-analysis

Expand the function $\frac{1}{z(1-z)}$ in a Laurent series, in the neighbourhood of the points $z = 0, \, z = 1, \, z = \infty$.

I know how to expand the function at $z = 0$ and at $z = 1$ but I have no idea how to expand the function in a neighborhood of $z = \infty$.

I know that the expansion is $- \sum _{n=2} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}$ for $\mid \, z \mid \, > 1$ but I do not know how it was obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the Laurent series of $f(z)$ at $\infty$ amounts to finding the Laurent series for $f(\frac{1}{z})$ at zero.

In this case, we have
$$ \frac{1}{z(1-z)}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}$$
and if $|z|>1$ then the latter expression can be expanded as a geometric series in $z^{-1}$, yielding
$$ \frac{1}{z(1-z)}=\frac{1}{z}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{-n}=-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}z^{-n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Define first $z=\frac 1x$ which makes $$\frac{1}{z(1-z)}=-\frac{x^2}{1-x}$$ Use the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ around $x=0$, multiply the result by $x^2$ and replace $x$ by $\frac 1z$.